# Filtered query on below mapping

Tags: java, performance, elasticsearch

I have created Elastic search mapping as below.

```
 PUT indexcloud  

  {
      "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
          "_all": {
            "enabled": false
          },
          "_source": {
            "compressed": true
          },
          "properties": {
            "term": {
              "fields": {
                "raw": {
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "analyzer": "lowercase_analyzer",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "analyzer": "concat_all_alpha",
              "type": "string"
            },
            "relation": {
            "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "term": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "concat_all_alpha",
                  "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                      "index": "not_analyzed",
                      "analyzer": "lowercase_analyzer",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                }

              }
            }


          }
        }
      },
      "settings": {
        "index": {
          "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
              "concat_all_alpha": {
                "char_filter": [
                  "only_alphanum"
                ],
                "filter": [
                  "lowercase"
                ],
                "tokenizer": "keyword"
              },
              "uppercase_analyzer": {
                "filter": "uppercase",
                "tokenizer": "keyword"
              },
              "lowercase_analyzer": {
                "filter": "lowercase",
                "tokenizer": "keyword"
              }
            },
            "char_filter": {
              "only_alphanum": {
                "pattern": "[^A-Z^a-z^0-9]|\\^",
                "replacement": "",
                "type": "pattern_replace"
              }
            }
          },
          "max_result_window": "1000000"
        }
      }
    }
```

Sample index doc

```
POST indexcloud/skill 
{"term":"Java Language","relation":[{"term":"java8"},{"term":"struct"},{"term":"j2ee"},{"term":"Progamming Language"}]}
```

I want to search using filtered query as below

```
GET indexcloud/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : { 
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "term" : "Java Language"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not working. How can i achieve this ?. Note :  i dont want like below

```
GET indexcloud/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : { 
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "term" : "javalanguage"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Because i want to search, the way i index.

Comment: Try to use the `raw`field: `"term" : {"term.raw" : "Java Language"}` but since you're lowercasing the terms in that field you might want to use `"term" : {"term.raw" : "java language"}` instead

Comment: I want to use analysed field so that user even search for  `Java-Language`. We are only keeping alphanumeric value for field.

Comment: "term" query is not analyzed so it goes to search "as is". Since You put lowercased words in index and search for 'Java Language" then it won't match ...
You should use "match" if You want to analyze input (and You can define search_analyzer as well). "Term" query should be used to search values 1:1 ...

Comment: I know i can use.  `GET indexcloud/_search { "query" : { "match": { "term" : "java language" } } }`   . Can i achieve using filter query ?.

Comment: no if You search in analyzed index which changed Your string. As I said - term is not analyzed, so it pass search term unchanged. You can't match "java" if You search 'Java" or "JaVa" in term query ... "term" is mostly for "strict" comparing (imput eg. comes from radio/checkbox/dropdown or is int)

Btw - You can use "match" inside filter query ... in Your example just change "term" to "match" and it'll work